# Link appears in browser, but the test says it's not there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a test in RSpec that checks for an edit link if one of the articles in the list belongs to the logged in user:

```
let(:user) { Fabricate(:user) }
before do
  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
  fill_in 'Password', :with => user.password
  click_button 'Sign in'
end

describe 'when user has a self-authored article' do
  let(:article) { Fabricate(:article, :author_id => user.id) }
  before { visit articles_path }
  it { should have_link('Edit article', :href => edit_article_path(article)) }
end
```

These are the views that it tests:

```
# articles/new.html.erb
<% provide(:title, 'Articles') %>
<h1>Articles</h1>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to 'Post article', new_article_path %>
<% end %>

<%= render @articles %>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

This is the specific view that it tests:

```
# articles/_article.html.erb
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.id == article.author.id %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit article', edit_article_path(article) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

> Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Edit article', :href =>
>   edit_article_path(article)) }
>
> ```
>    expected link "Edit article" to return something
> ```

I checked my browser to confirm that the test is right, but the link seems to appear as intended. Where did I go wrong? How do I make the test pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. It turns out that I had a misunderstanding of how `let` works. I thought it could be executed before `before`, but I was wrong. I fixed the issue by fabricating the object inside the `before` block

```
describe 'when user has a self-authored article' do
    before do
      @article = Fabricate(:article, :author_id => user.id)
      visit articles_path
    end
    it { should have_link('Edit article', :href => edit_article_path(@article)) }
  end
end
```

Comment: You can force the behaviour you expected by using `let!` instead of `let`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `let(:article) { Fabricate(:user, :author_id => user.id) }` is creating a user, not an article.